# iOS get the system accessibility zoom type

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, zooming

In iOS, user can select a zoom level in the accessibility settings. I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve that zoom level from an app to make UI changes accordingly. There are notifications for fonts:

```
UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification
```

But I can't find anything regarding the zoom level. The only clue I got is this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/zoomtype

which seems to be used for us to notify the system using the method:

```
zoomFocusChanged(zoomType:toFrame:in:)
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not